# Redirect domain URI via htaccess

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to setup the following redirect via .htaccess:

http://domain/something/my_post
to
http://domain/otherthing/my_post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Redirect /something/ /otherthing/
```

Comment: I have already tried that, but I need all the links redirected:
http://domain.com/something/my_post to http://domain.com/otherthing/my_post
OR
http://domain.com/something/help_about to
http://domain.com/otherthing/help_about

Comment: That redirect *everything* after `/something/` to the same place but starting with `/otherthing/`. It redirects all links.

Comment: OMG, i have tried various more advanced redirects, but did not though that this will do the job. Thanks in tons!